# Style JSON results from a search

Tags: json, dictionary

If I make the search:

```
http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=dict_api.callbacks.id100&q=school&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr%2Cde&client=te
```

I end up with a response in JSON. I am not a programmer and I have no idea where to begin to take the results and then style them and turn them into something my students can read?

Comment: For a non-programmer, you're doing pretty well getting this far. :-) But it may be time to hand off to a programmer.

Comment: Thanks, and I agree. I am at a HELP ME point. I guess I will be looking for a freelancer.

Answer (score 2):

No offense, but if you're not a programmer, than perhaps returning the results in JSON is not a good plan? JSON requires something to interpret the results before display; generally javascript, but there are plenty of JSON parsers for other languages, and it's becoming a pretty common standard.

Regardless, you'll need to parse the results with something, and then display the results in something else. You'll need programming experience for this.

Comment: No offense taken. I know my weakness' and I try to learn what I can. I think a programmer is what I will be looking for next.

Comment: Perhaps if you described what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am a teacher, my students are 7-8 years old. I want to have a search box on my website that searches a dictionary and displays the results in a block on my site. Most of the dictionaries are too complex for my students and have inappropriate ads. So I thought the results from google/dictionary.com were perfect. I just do not want my students to leave my site. So that is what brought me here.

Comment: Yep, sounds like you'll need a programmer to rock this out for you. If you're a teacher, I imagine you have a programming class at some level in your school? This would be a simple project, and a good exercise in a programming class.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with jvenema that JSON might not be the right format for you. However, you can try this JSON-visualizer and see if it fits your needs:

http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm

You will need to select "Eval" instead of strict "JSON" and trim the leading:

```
dict_api.callbacks.id100(
```

and the trailing:

```
,200,null)
```

before you click "Render" to get a good result.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I trimmed it and saw the results. I agree with both of you. However I am not sure how else to get the results from the search. I can get them in an Iframe but them I am very limited to what I can do with it.